# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\?(?<query>.*)/: Invalid group

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I've been working on a parser for url queries but I'm stumped on why the regex is incorrect when it worked during test via [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) ***or atleast I think it did, it's been a late night coding***;

Anyway I haven't found any answers searching both StackOverflow or Good Ol'e google.

Issue: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\?(?<query>.*)/: Invalid group`

```js
   const results = url.match(/\?(?<query>.*)/);
    if (!results) {
        return {};
    }
    const { groups: { query } } = results;

    const pairs = query.match(/(?<param>\w+)=(?<value>\w+)/g);
    const params = pairs.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const [key, value] = curr.split(("="));
        acc[key] = value;
        return acc;
    }, {});
    return params;
```

Comment: Is Node JS not ecmascript ? I thought JS was controlled by browsers.

Comment: @Maxt8r JS can run on many platforms. It's true that it's most widely seen on client's browsers, but it can also run on a server on the backend (with Node.js), or on desktop applications (with Electron), and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named capture groups are only supported in Node 10+, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Browser_compatibility). You need to update your Node version. (Node versions below 10 are [very old](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/), it'd be a good idea to update even were it not for this issue)

If for some reason you're not permitted to do that, you can make it a normal capture group rather than a named capture group:

```
/\?(.*)/
```

and then extract the first group from the match (`[1]`). Same thing for extracting the pairs from the query string.

On modern versions of Node, you can also use the more semantic `Object.fromEntries` instead of `reduce`:

```
const params = Object.fromEntries(
  pairs.map(pair => pair.split('='))
);
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't even realise my node was on `v8.11.4` lol; I haven't been on this PC in a long time. thanks for the advice.

Comment: Sorry, @CertainPerformance
I forgot to do so, just done it now; I was rushing around xD